# Autocomplete not working for android xml files on Netbeans

Tags: android, netbeans, autocomplete, netbeans-plugins

**Details**

- Netbeans is 7.3.1
- NBAndroid is 1.153
- Android SDK is up to date and my project uses API level 17.

Answer (score 0):

This is incomplete. Please tell us more details about what you are doing. What files, what do you expect to be completed, reproducible test case (attach sample from your project)...? It is possible that the feature is not implemented or that there is a problem. Of course nbandroid project has its website where you can find http://nbandroid.org/wiki/index.php/Contacts